# Debugging Java running in WSL with VSCode running in Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Set "console": "integratedTerminal" in my launch.json. My integrated terminal is WSL. Looking to see if there's an easy way to debug programs that are launched within WSL from my VSCode instance running in Windows.

When executing Gradle tasks like build or run from within my integrated terminal things work fine, but can't figure out an easy way to debug the program.

Comment: Is this not currently possible, or there really is no interest in this?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: This was posted so long ago, I forget that I even did! VS Code has native WSL support now through a plugin. See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl

Comment: Awesome, thank you.